# Apache poi-ooxml schemas gives outofmemory error during deployment

Tags: java, apache, out-of-memory, websphere, apache-poi

I have apache poi-ooxml schema jar file in my application. When I am trying to deploy the ear through websphere, I am getting outOfMemory error. When i remove this jar file from ear and try to deploy then it gets deployed.

Does anybody know what exactly is the heap space required for this jar file?

I get this error

```
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".
java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.lockFile(FileSystemPreferences.java:896)
        at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.sync(FileSystemPreferences.java:725)
        at java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.flush(FileSystemPreferences.java:818
```

Comment: Can you give any code or other information? Put them in your question.

Comment: Using this library, i'm trying to read the excel file. Could you please let me know what other information is required?

Comment: Heap Space is normally needed when you run Java code, not load it!

Comment: added the error stack. Can someone please help me to analyze this?